# Changing values of an array which consists of multiple objects

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to replace a value within the `path` array and I'm quite stuck for a while. So here is what I got.

**My array:**

```
// $myArr
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bob
                            [1] => pictures
                            [2] => food
                        )
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc] => stdClass Object
                (

                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Alice
                            [1] => pictures
                            [2] => vacations
                            [3] => rome
                        )
                )

        )
)
```

**PHP code:**

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($myArr) ; $i++) { 
    $search  = array($old_name); // pictures
    $replace = array($new_name); // test
    $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $myArr[$i]->doc->path);       
}
```

**Result:**

It only changes one array and gives me a hint on my `str_replace` line. Both, `$search` and `$replace` are of type `array` and I know that I need to access elements in an array via array notation -> $item['price'] for example. That is not what is wrong here right?

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob
    [1] => test
    [2] => food
)
```

1) Do you see why he only modifies the last object so to speak?

2) Why is he giving me a Notice whereas I don't violate type conventions in my opinion?

Comment: Unlike javascript, associative arrays are not objects in php.

Comment: @TimMorton This means I should rather work with the JSON representation of my array. Is this that what you are trying to say? Can't really follow you unfortunately.

Comment: Your issue cannot be replicated.  Please edit your question to offer a testable portion of code and sample data that generates the Notice.  Otherwise your question may be closed as off-topic. 
 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5385b8ba41520d0077d205f9e5413daae7c1527

Comment: My point was that it looked like you're confusing arrays and objects.  The error code is saying that you were treating something that wasn't an object as if it were. Your comment, `array notation -> $item['price'] ` further looked like you were thinking of an object as an array. In hindsight, I think I just misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine on my end, however..

I think the problem is in your `$result` variable. With every iteration, you are overwriting the last written value in the array.

You have to either use that `$result` variable directly, or replace `$result` by `$myArr[$i]->doc->path`. That way you can use the $myArr with the rewritten values.

Comment: This is not an answer to the issue.  Advising about making `$result` an array is a helpful comment, but not an answer (please move answer to a comment).  Until the OP can write a question with a reproduce-able error in it, this question is off-topic and shouldn't be answered.